# comparison in PHP get invalid result?

Tags: php

I just found found this simple comparison getting true. Can someone explain why or point me a link that explain it?

```
<?php
var_dump((897 == "897,898,906,907,884"));
```

Comment: Have you tried with `===` instead? If not, the right hand side is coerced into an integer value and the expression will yield `true`.

Comment: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I know about `===`. but `==` will return false for `(897 == "897898")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare integer and string, the string is converted to integer.

For example :

```
var_dump((int)"897,898,906,907,884");
```

Give you :

```
int 897
```

So that's why the result is `true`.

Please check this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Why that compared as int instead of string?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.